# Can my location be tracked/can my phone be duplicated

Tags: sms

I believe someone is keeping track of me via my phone. Is this possible and, if so, what can I do to disable that? Also, is it possible for someone who has had access to my phone to duplicate it so that they can see my texts?

Comment: I don't think so. Your phone is rooted?

Comment: Basically, if someone got physical access, he could have installed a tracking app and something that forwards your SMS – there are apps for both things available. There might even be some which are "cloaking" (i.e. hiding from the user). If you suspect something like that, first step would be checking installed apps for suspicious candidates (i.e. user-installed apps which *you* didn't install). Hard to do a remote diagnostic on that.

Comment: If someone has access to your Google Account, they could track your device via that.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as there is no details in your question I'll answer in general: if you've got an android device - you could be tracked. This is not only about some sort of embedded Google telemetry or hidden spying apk - any app, that has permission to access your sms/camera/other data can do so.

This is how it may look like:

[image: app permissions example]:

Of course there are couple of ways to avoid such a mess

1. Download and install XPrivacy. It's free application and it's rather hard to use, but this is the most clean way as soon as this app is opensource. Further instructions[here](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy#installation). **[Root](http://www.androidcentral.com/root) access required**.
2. Use other restricting permission app: there are [plenty](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=restrict%20permissions&c=apps&docType=1) and [here](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy#similar-solutions) is the quick comparsion. Check out [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/playpermissionsexposed-fix-play-store-t2783076) and [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-crappalinks-remove-link-masking-t2603868) tool. **May require root access**.
3. Freeze suspected apps which receives sms. [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.pro&hl=en) tool could do the trick. **Root access required**.
4. Just do not install any app that desires sms privilege - kinda tricky but the only way if previous are not possible.